# ASCII text file load to SQL and code page issues

Tags: ssis

I have a ACSII text file which contains strange characters (not readable).
I would like to load to SQL Server. I selected the data type "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" in the advanced editor as the file contains unreadable and looks like Unicode. I got this error:

> [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Address Array" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

I have the Unicode `ntext nvarchar(MAX)` on the SQL table as well.

But the error is coming even before loading the file, just reading the file and not sending the output anywhere.

The data in the Address Array field looks like this: "PQýMONTREALýýýMASTERCARD PAYMENT CENTREýýýýýýP.O. BOX 6044 STN.CENTRE-VILLEýCANADAýCAýPQýQUEBECýH3C3X2". This data is in an ASCII text file. Any data type on sql side will work as I have to load the data and can use any data type. I have even tried with TEXT and NTEXT.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Which component in your SSIS package is the error occurring on?

Comment: got it, I will not mention urgent again, sorry.

Comment: The error is occuring on flat file reading, ssis can read the file but complain as the error pasted in the posting.  Its "flat file source" task.

Comment: ý is not in the ASCII character set so it can't be in a text file written with the ASCII character encoding. The first step in reading a text file is knowing the character encoding it was written with. Go back to the source and find out.